# configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'myvars'

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

I have a config file `/tools/inputs/masterinputs.txt` with this content:

```
[myvars]
maplat: 32.636004
maplon: -115.437702
```

I use `configparser` to read it:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()              
config.read("/tools/inputs/masterinputs.txt")
maplat = float(config.get("myvars", "maplat"))
```

But I get this error message:

```
root@Primerpi:/tools# python3 solarrobot7-core.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/configparser.py", line 1109, in _unify_values
    sectiondict = self._sections[section]
KeyError: 'myvars'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solarrobot7-core.py", line 33, in <module>
    maplat = float(config.get("myvars", "maplat"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/configparser.py", line 771, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/configparser.py", line 1112, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'myvars'
```

The file contains the section `[myvars]` and it it obviously reads the config file. So I'm at a loss as to what is causing this error.

Comment: "*As you can see the file*" - no, I can't, because you have not included the file in your post.  BTW, the `#!` line is having no effect, it **must** be the very first line in the file, no comments, white-space, nothing, before it.

Comment: thank you.  i thought i had included it as well.  i have deleted the first line which starts with a # and will run it again and see what happens.  Thanks again for replying!

Comment: i deleted this line #masterinputs.txt to be placed in /tools/inputs/, but the error output remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

The docs make it clear (emphasis mine):

> ```
> Signature: config.read(filenames, encoding=None)
> ```
>
> Docstring:
>   Read and parse a filename or a list of filenames.
>
> **Files that cannot be opened are silently ignored**; this is
>   designed so that you can specify a list of potential
>   configuration file locations (e.g. current directory, user's
>   home directory, systemwide directory), and all existing
>   configuration files in the list will be read.  A single
>   filename may also be given.

Python cannot find the file.

Add this at the beginning of your file:

```
import os

assert os.path.exists('/tools/inputs/masterinputs.txt')
```

If you get past these lines, you should see output, provided the file contains the content shown.

BTW, you can use:

```
maplat = config.getfloat('myvars', "maplat")
```

to retrieve a float.

Comment: Will try your suggestions, Mike.  i like your "maplat =" suggestion as well.  It makes me want to go back and work on it already! - lol.

Comment: Done!  the blinkin' file was really masterinputs..txt and my eyes just never saw the extra ".".  Thanks to all who helped!

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.